# can not sign out - always signed in using php session and cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, logout, unset

I'm using this function to create a sign in session and cookie

```
function startSession($time,$ses) {
   session_set_cookie_params($time,'/','.domain.com',false,true); 
   // if I use www.domain.com the session won't start and the user won't be able to sign in
   session_name($ses);
   if(session_id() == '') {
       session_start();
   }
   if (isset($_COOKIE[$ses]))
       setcookie($ses, $_COOKIE[$ses], time() + $time, "/");
}
```

the login page contains this code in the head

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',99999999);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',99999999);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies' , true);
if(session_id() == '') {
   session_start();
}
```

and if credentials are correct I call the function

```
startSession($time = '99999999', $ses = 'mySession');
```

and add values to it as an array

```
$_SESSION['mySession'][0] = 'value1';
$_SESSION['mySession'][1] = 'value2';
```

Then redirect the user to the index page which contains this code in the head

```
startSession($time = '99999999', $ses = 'mySession');
```

The sign out page contains this code

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['mySession']);
session_destroy();
unset($_COOKIE['mySession']);
setcookie('mySession', null, -999999999, '/');
$_SESSION['mySession'] = array();
$_SESSION['mySession'][0]=' ';
$_SESSION['mySession'][1]=' ';
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Then the user gets redirected again to the index page but the sign out process does not work and the user gets signed in again automatically.
What makes the user gets signed in again though unsetting the session and the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is quite a simple solution to login and logout.

**Login:**

```
<?php
# Firstly:
session_start();

# Suppose authentication is successful and you have a user array...
# $user = array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'Rayn', 'email' => 'xyz@gmail.com');

# Now you want to log that user in.

$_SESSION['user'] = $user;

# Now if I want to add the cookie.
setcookie('user', $user, time()+3600*24*30, '/');
# It is time() + 30 Days.

# Now check in your protected pages...
if (!empty($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['user] = $_COOKIE['user'];
}

#and focus your concentration on the session.
if (empty($_SESSION['user])) {
    // Redirect him to the login page.
}
?>
```

**Logout:**

```
<?php
# Firstly:
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']);
setcookie('user', NULL, time() - 3600*24, '/');
# It is actually time() - 24 Hours. 
# You have wrote only -[some time value]. Which is a negative time.
?>
```

Hope this helps.